# Is there a utility for Mac that shows the information of an SSD like the health etc...?

Tags: macos, mac, ssd

I am wondering if there is a utility for the Mac that allows you to see the details of an SSD like the health of the drive, TBW (total bites written), how many running hours etc...

In researching for an app of such a kind I found  ([SSDLife](http://ssd-life.com)) for Windows, which looks to me like it does exactly what I would need. The most important information that I need to know about is the TBW (total bites written) on the drive. This is because I have heard that once an SSD drive reaches a certain amount of writes it becomes a read only drive, so this information would be invaluable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show a SMART report with `brew install smartmontools; smartctl -a disk0` or [SMARTReporter](http://www.corecode.at/smartreporter/index.html). The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) has descriptions of the different attributes.

The SMART reports of some SSDs show how much data has been written to the disk. Mine doesn't though. Dividing the raw values of the [unused and unused reserved block counts](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/manual-en/HealthStatus.html) might also indicate the health of a drive. Mine are 894 and 3266, but I don't know how to interpret that. The reserved block count is [the number of reserved spares for bad block handling](http://code.google.com/p/hddguardian/wiki/SandForce_SMART_attributes). The SSD life left value of some other drives is based on the number of used reserved blocks and PE cycles.

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       7726
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       2939
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0013   253   253   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       3839973395584
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   187   187   100    Old_age   Always       -       700105949460
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
176 Erase_Fail_Count_Chip   0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   095   095   017    Pre-fail  Always       -       163
178 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Chip  0x0013   075   075   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       524
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   078   078   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       894
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0013   078   078   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       3266
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2883
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   062   062   000    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 22/63)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

Comment: Thanks, that information is very helpful. I got this question closed once and so I decided to redo it and be more descriptive but then it still got down voted. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. I thought that this question was a very good question and I couldn't understand why I was getting all the negativity.

Comment: We've almost disallowed software recommendation questions in the FAQ. I think they're OK in cases like this though.